# Plotly Scatterplot3d display x-y grid that does not "climb" z-axis

Tags: python, plotly, scatter3d

[image: Desired plot (Pang 2021)]

[image: My plot with gridlines on z-axis]

I am currently trying to rebuild the plot from the first figure (from Pang et al 2021) in plotly. However I do not find a setting in which I can prevent the x-y grid to also climb up to z axis (second figure). My code is the following.

```
f.update_layout(
    scene = dict(
        xaxis = dict(
            gridcolor = "black",
            showbackground = False
        ),
        yaxis = dict(
            showbackground = False,
            gridcolor = "black"
        ),
        zaxis = dict(
            showbackground = False
        )
))
```